# Rename MySQL table and set prefix in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I already coded an entire platform in PHP but had to switch web host. The script requires MySQL tables such as 'users','records', etc.
The problem is that the database has to be installed on the same database but there is already a table name users for a previous script.
If I rename the table to (e.g) 'foo_users', how can I let the entire script know that 'users' is now 'foo_users' without editing all pages?

Comment: Do you have an include file which is common to all the php files?

Comment: @Akshay yes the database connection file "config.php"

Comment: It might sound a little stupid, but why don't you use the `search in files` feature of sublime text, search for the required tablename, and replace it with the new tablename?

Answer (score 0):

Generally you should use different databases for different applications. That way there will not be any naming conflicts and permissions etc. can be managed separately.

Some software have a setting called "table prefix" which is useful if you need to run several instances of the same software in a single database instance. You should check if one of the two applications have this feature and change the table names in that application and set the table prefix.

Comment: Yeah I know about the table prefix but It was made to b used in it's own database but that was before I switched web host. I developed both applications from scratch. No framework, no CMS. It would take alot of time going through the code and changing table names. Is that the only option?